# Title and footnote with Proc Greplay

Tags: graph, sas

I trying a Proc Greplay with loop so to Generate all the graphs in a same page from a catalog. 
here I am not able to give a title or footnote for the final graph. the code is as here:

```
PROC GREPLAY NOFS IGOUT=&igout ;
 %if &gout ^= %then GOUT=&gout;
 ;
 TC TEMPLT;
 %include "PANELS.SAS" ;
 TEMPLATE MULTIGRF;

 %let totalplots=%eval(&columns*&rows);

 %do i = 1 %to &nobs %by &totalplots;
 TREPLAY
 %let box = 1;
 %let plot = &i;
 %do %until (&box>&totalplots or &plot>&nobs);
 &box:&plot
 %let box = %eval(&box+1);
 %let plot = %eval(&plot+1);
 %end;
 ;
 %end;
 QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to add titles/footnotes - you will need to do a few steps:

When you create your template MULTIGRF, you need to create another panel that covers 100% of the page.

Create your titles and footnotes in a PROC GSLIDE and save to your graph catalog.

Modify your macro code and add another iteration that will replay your GSLIDE output to the panel that is the full page.

One option is to define all of your boxes/panels to cover 90% of the page and leave 5% margin at the top and bottom of the page to allow for titles and footnotes to be replayed without overlaying on your graphs.

Here is a nice SAS paper with an example:
http://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2011/cs/CS01.pdf

Comment: Ja, 
I got it. What I did was almost same as you said but dint add an iteration. 

Added another Prog Greplay to the macro, saved the Gslide to a catalog and output template from graphs also to the same catalog and ran the second Proc Greply with 100% gslide and 90% graph template. :)